# Heading with picture, rulers & multiple lines in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to figure out without success following header scheme:

```
_______
|      |  | Text                                        TEXT
| Pic  |  | ________________________________________________
|______|  | Text              TEXT                      TEXT
```

I used fancyhdr, however I was not able to figure out, how to put a ruler
on the whole line, fancyhdr allowed me to put the rulers just under the text
of L/C/R. Also I was not able to create the vertical ruler. With the picture I gave up. as I spend a lot of time to figure the rulers out.

I was thinking to use the myheadings style with markboth command, however, I'm not able to break lines and LaTeX put's everything on one line, even when trying to use \newline command or so.

```
\documentclass{12pt, twoside}{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\markboth{}{Left text \hfill center text \hfill right text \newline second line left}

\begin{document}
Page 1
\newpage
Page 2
\end{document}
```

Any hints, where should I start?

Thank you very much

Comment: Consider the three-part layout of `fancyhdr` as just a suggestion -- nothing prevents you from leaving either of Left, Center, and Right part empty. Now, start thinking about using a `\parbox` or `minipage` -- this gives you the freedom to insert linebreaks, rules, etc. If you are really using the `article` class -- i.e. a class with one-sided layout --, this approach should be rather easy; with a two-side layout (`book`, `report`) you'd have to consider facing pages. I'll try to come up with an example for `article` later on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints and possible example. Meanwhile I'll take a look on minipage and parbox. I was trying to use it as well, however, failed.
Regarding doctype, well, would be nice to have it also for report, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Just a starting point, because it may need some adjustments according to what are the actual texts.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\setlength{\headheight}{39pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \raisebox{2.5ex}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.84\textwidth}@{}}
            Left text \hfill Right text \\
            \hline
            \rule{0pt}{14pt}Second line left \hfill Center text \hfill Second line right
        \end{tabular}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \raisebox{2.5ex}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.84\textwidth}|}
            Left text \hfill  Right text \\
            \hline
            \rule{0pt}{14pt}Second line left \hfill Center text \hfill Second line right
        \end{tabular}}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
Page 1
\blindtext
\newpage
Page 2
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, I'll study it and adjust according to my needs. Nevertheless it's very close to what I need and it's a perfect material how to etc. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it took me so long to get this working. Nevertheless, as I just completed my solution, I'll post it even though it may be similar to that of CarLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1-20}     % Make sure we get enough dummy text to fill several pages

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%% Define variables for the text fields
%% Please note: They resemble the scheme from the fancyhdr documentation,
%%              but we will use only one of the fields from fancyhdr to place the text!

% Set contents of the textfields
\newcommand{\fhtexttl}{Text top left}
\newcommand{\fhtexttr}{Text top right}
\newcommand{\fhtextbl}{Text bottom left}
\newcommand{\fhtextbc}{Text bottom center}
\newcommand{\fhtextbr}{Text bottom right}

% For twoside classes (e.g. book, report}, we need to shuffle things around
% First, define variables for odd pages
\newcommand{\fhoddtl}{\fhtexttl}
\newcommand{\fhoddtr}{\fhtexttr}
\newcommand{\fhoddbl}{\fhtextbl}
\newcommand{\fhoddbc}{\fhtextbc}
\newcommand{\fhoddbr}{\fhtextbr}

% Now, define variables for even pages -- everything is mirrored
\newcommand{\fheventl}{\fhtexttr}
\newcommand{\fheventr}{\fhtexttl}
\newcommand{\fhevenbl}{\fhtextbr}
\newcommand{\fhevenbc}{\fhtextbc}
\newcommand{\fhevenbr}{\fhtextbl}

%% Define the image we use
\newcommand{\fhimage}{example-image-a}
\newsavebox{\fhlogo}

% Set width of image
\newlength{\fhimagewidth}
\setlength{\fhimagewidth}{2cm}

\sbox{\fhlogo}{\includegraphics[width=\fhimagewidth]{\fhimage}}

% Calculate height of image
\newlength{\fhimageheight}
\setlength{\fhimageheight}{\totalheightof{\usebox{\fhlogo}}}

% Set distance between image, vertical line, and the other header field
\newlength{\fhimagesep}
\setlength{\fhimagesep}{\widthof{~}}

% Set width of the vertical line between image and text
\newlength{\fhimagerulewidth}
\setlength{\fhimagerulewidth}{.5pt}

% Calculate width of textfield
\newlength{\fhtextwidth}
\setlength{\fhtextwidth}
          {\textwidth-\fhimagewidth-2\fhimagesep-\fhimagerulewidth}

% Define spacer inserted at begin/end of text lines in textfield
% so the horizontal line extends beyond the textlines
% (Note: '~' is ignored everywhere but at the start of the first line, so we use a \rule here)
\newcommand{\fhtextspacer}{\rule{\fhimagesep}{0pt}}

%% Clear all headers
\fancyhead{}

%% Set up headers for right (odd pages)
% Logo
\fancyhead[LO]{%
    \usebox{\fhlogo}%
    \rule{\fhimagesep}{0pt}%
    \rule{\fhimagerulewidth}{\fhimageheight}%
    \rule{\fhimagesep}{0pt}%
}

% Text
\fancyhead[RO]{%
    \parbox[b][\fhimageheight][c]{\fhtextwidth}
              {%
                \fhtextspacer\fhoddtl\hfill\fhoddtr\fhtextspacer\\[-.5\baselineskip]%
                \rule{\fhtextwidth}{.5pt}\\%
                \fhtextspacer\fhoddbl\hfill\fhoddbc\hfill\fhoddbr\fhtextspacer%
              }%
}


%% Set up headers for left (even pages)
% Logo
\fancyhead[RE]{%
    \rule{\fhimagesep}{0pt}%
    \rule{\fhimagerulewidth}{\fhimageheight}%
    \rule{\fhimagesep}{0pt}%
    \usebox{\fhlogo}%
}

% Text
\fancyhead[LE]{%
    \parbox[b][\fhimageheight][c]{\fhtextwidth}
              {%
                \fhtextspacer\fheventl\hfill\fheventr\fhtextspacer\\[-.5\baselineskip]%
                \rule{\fhtextwidth}{.5pt}\\%
                \fhtextspacer\fhevenbl\hfill\fhevenbc\hfill\fhevenbr\fhtextspacer%
              }%
}

% Set this to the header height actually needed
\setlength{\headheight}{48pt}

% Uncomment the following line if you don't want to have a line below the complete header!
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Andreas, I'm also very grateful for your example and I'll definitely look at it! Also bit thank to you!